How to properly reload a module in Python
This question has been asked many times, here are a few for reference:
Reimport a module while interactive
Proper way to reload a python module from the console
How to reload a module's function in Python?
From what I searched and learned, I have wrote the following but it fails to properly reload the module:
import pandas as pd

pd.get_option('display.width')  # 80

pd.set_option("display.width", 150)

del pd

import importlib

import sys

pd = importlib.reload(sys.modules['pandas'])

pd.get_option('display.width')  # 150


Your module (pandas) in this case is actually reloaded, but importlib.reload does not clear internal memory of module-level variables, it merely re-executes the module’s code. Now, the value of the module variables after reload depends on the way it was initialized. If you define your module m.py like
x = 0
try:
    y
except NameError:
    y = 0

you can see the difference in behavior:
>>> import importlib
>>> import m
>>> m.x
0
>>> m.y
0
>>> m.x = 1
>>> m.y = 1
>>> _ = importlib.reload(m)
>>> m.x
0
>>> m.y
1


Ah this makes so much sense, thank you. I guess it's best to run my code in a new process then. The Python imports has been a recurring issue for me especially when I'm making a small web interface using Google's Mesop along with using config managers such as yacs.
